# Oracle: why does the SQL code work in a view, but not in a materialized view?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, view, materialized-views

I need to change some SQL code that is in a view to a materialized view.

But when I copy and use it, I get an error:

> ORA-32480: SEARCH and CYCLE clauses can only be specified for recursive WITH clause elements

I don't understand why what works in view also works in mat. view.

Does anybody have an idea how I can get rid of the error? The problem occurs with a join where another query is called. I also tried the recursive with, but that didn't work somehow.

```
with
  z1  (einheit_id, ancestor_einheit_id, ueb_einheit_id, is_root, kiste_id, nodepath)  as (
       select     e.id as einheit_id, e.id as ancestor_einheit_id, e.ueb_einheit_id, 0 as is_root,  e.kiste_id, cast(to_char(e.id) as varchar2(1024)) as nodepath
       from       r_be_einheit e
       where      e.kiste_id = -2
       union all
       select     z1.einheit_id, coalesce(e1.id,e2.id) as ancestor_einheit_id, coalesce(e1.ueb_einheit_id, e2.ueb_einheit_id) as ueb_einheit_id,
                  0 as is_root, coalesce(e1.kiste_id,e2.kiste_id) as kiste_id,
                  z1.nodepath ||  '/' || cast(to_char(coalesce(e1.id,e2.id)) as varchar2(1024)) as nodepath                 
       from       z1
       left join  r_be_einheit e1 on e1.id = z1.ueb_einheit_id
       left join  r_be_einheit e2 on e2.merge_einheit_id = z1.ancestor_einheit_id
       where      z1.is_root = 0 and (e1.id is not null or e2.id is not null) and instr(z1.nodepath, '/' || to_char(coalesce(e1.id,e2.id))) = 0
       )  cycle nodepath set is_cycle to 1 default 0
    ,
    einheiten as (
    select      e.id as be_einheit_id,
                e.barcode,
                e.objektart_id
    from        r_be_einheit e
    left join   z1 on e.id = z1.einheit_id
  )
  ,
  og_zuo0 as (
    select e.barcode
    from  einheiten e
  )
  ,
  og_zuo1 as (
    select *
    from einheiten e
    join og_zuo0 on og_zuo0.barcode = e.barcode
  )
  select * from og_zuo1
```

i got the code very far down that the error still shows up. i got the code very far down that the error still shows up.
It is the last join. If I delete og_zuo1 and select og_zuo0 at the end then the error does not appear.But I don't understand why.

Comment: Be aware that the query you specify in a materialized view is only used *once*, when the MV is created. After that, Oracle creates its own query behind the scenes to accomplish refreshes, using its own constructs, hints, etc., and there is no way to control that process. If you continue to have issues, consider creating this query as a standard view and use a simple `select ... from my_view` query in the materialized view definition; that way you maintain control of the critical parts of your query.

Comment: unfortunately the error also occurs like this

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the code as:

```sql
with z1  (einheit_id, ancestor_einheit_id, ueb_einheit_id, is_root, kiste_id, nodepath) as (
  select id,
         id,
         ueb_einheit_id,
         0,
         kiste_id,
         cast(to_char(id) as varchar2(1024))
  from   r_be_einheit
  where  kiste_id = -2
union all
  select z1.einheit_id,
         coalesce(e1.id,e2.id),
         coalesce(e1.ueb_einheit_id, e2.ueb_einheit_id),
         0,
         coalesce(e1.kiste_id,e2.kiste_id) as kiste_id,
         z1.nodepath ||  '/' || to_char(coalesce(e1.id,e2.id))
  from   z1
         left join  r_be_einheit e1
         on e1.id = z1.ueb_einheit_id
         left join  r_be_einheit e2
         on e2.merge_einheit_id = z1.ancestor_einheit_id
  where  z1.is_root = 0
  and    (e1.id is not null or e2.id is not null)
  and    instr(z1.nodepath, '/' || to_char(coalesce(e1.id,e2.id))) = 0
) cycle nodepath set is_cycle to 1 default 0,
einheiten as (
  select e.id as be_einheit_id,
         e.barcode,
         e.objektart_id
  from   r_be_einheit e
         left join z1
         on e.id = z1.einheit_id
)
select e.*,
       e0.barcode
from   einheiten e
       join einheiten e0
       on e0.barcode = e.barcode
```

Although I'm not sure what the value of the self-join is in the final query; but it is there because it replicates the join in `og_zuo1`. You could rewrite the final two queries as:

```sql
einheiten as (
  select e.id as be_einheit_id,
         e.barcode,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.barcode) AS num_rows,
         e.objektart_id
  from   r_be_einheit e
         left join z1
         on e.id = z1.einheit_id
)
select e.*,
       e.barcode
from   einheiten e
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= e.num_rows
       )
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q76f3hiG)

Comment: With this query, i have the same error, if i use it in a materialized view

Comment: actually is in og_zuo0 and og_zuo1 more joins and other things, have taken out only to the overview and to the error search